# jQuery selector is getting duplicated elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I've got a problem with jQuery selectors. I'm calling this:

```
var keysContainerRows = $(".prockeyscontainer").find(".row");
console.log(keysContainerRows);
```

And this is what I'm getting:

[image]

Selector is returning two elements with class `row` but there's only one element with class `row` inside element with class `prockeyscontainer`. This is the HTML:

[image]

What's happening here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many with the class `prockeyscontainer` ?

Comment: Sounds impossible. Fire up your local Debugger on site and check for `document.querySelectorAll('.prockeyscontainer').length;`

Comment: is there more than one element on the page with the class  `.prockeyscontainer`?

Comment: @jAndy I'm executing that sentence and I'm getting 2, which explains the unexpected returning result but I can't find the second element with .prockeyscontainer class! Any ideas of how to locate it? Just one in the HTML code.

Comment: You can search for HTML in the DOM inspector

Comment: It seems like a work for my crystall ball

Comment: If you're using Chrome (at least), then in the console.log out, expand n.fn.init[2] then expand the >0 and/or >1.  When you point at these, it will highlight the node on the page (assuming it's visible...)

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I'm prepending `.prockeyscontainer` dynamically with jQuery this way:

```
$("<div class='prockeyscontainer'></div>").prependTo(el_container);
```

Where `el_container` object contains this:

```
var el_container = $(data).appendTo($("body"));
```

Where `data` object contains this:

```
<head xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/index.css"/>
</head>

<div class='addkeysdialogv2'>
  . . . . . (Content) . . . . .
</div>
```

So `.prockeyscontainer` element was being prepended to `head` element and `addkeysdialogv2` element as well. I guess `el_container` was an `array` of two elements (`head` and `div`) returned by `appendTo` function. So when I was prepending a new element: `.prockeyscontainer` to `el_container` it was being applied to both array elements.